# Lottery Generator

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay guys I need your help. I'm creating a lottery number generator and it's supposed to ask the user how many numbers s/he wants to pick. After that it's supposed to create an array to hold that many (whatever the user enters) numbers, and then create that many random numbers (between 1 and 99) and fill the array with the random numbers. I have gotten it to create a random number between 1-99 and store it in a single array and display it. My problem is when the user picks how many numbers they want, I can't get it to create an array with that many random numbers in it. Do you guys have any solutions?

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/nfinsand/pen/KyqvyV
```

Comment: Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = lottoNums[i];
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML + ' - ' + lottoNums[i];
```